# looking for a http client in scala that handles redirects

Tags: scala, httpclient

I am looking for a http client in scala, that handles redirects. How do I fetch the content of a Url in scala, handling redirects?

I saw the scala.io.Source examples, but they dont handle redirects.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a Scala-only library? There are several Java libraries.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for _the scala way_ to to it. In Java I probably would use the jakarta commons http client. Is there a more scala way to fetch http content?

Comment: Couldn't you just take the existing Scala code and add redirect handling?

Comment: I dont't know how I find the Url that I should fetch next, the destination of the redirect. I only see the IOException.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) (which is probably better for anything beyond toy examples), you can tinker with the `URLConnection`:

```
def urlToStream(url: String) = Source.fromInputStream(
  (new java.net.URL(url).openConnection match {
    case connection: java.net.HttpURLConnection => {
      connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)
      connection
    }
    case connection => connection
  }).getInputStream
)
```

This will turn on redirect following if the protocol is HTTP.

Comment: This throws an exception whenever it encounters wide characters: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1. If I set the encoding to ISO-8859-1, it works for me.  IOW, change the code to }).getInputStream, "IOS-8859-1"

Answer (score 4):

You can use Finagle to [build a client](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/master/finagle-example/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/example/http/HttpClient.scala). It is pretty low-level though, working directly at the `HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse]` level, so it requires a small amount of work to get it to handle a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check out Dispatch? http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html

It wraps HttpClient, so you can do anything HttpClient can do, but in a Scala way. IMO, it's a bit heavy on weird operators, and should spell more things out, but I have been using it for a year or two and like many things about it.